# Finding a square in a blank image

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

Let's say I have a JPG image that's completely white except for a green filled in square that's placed randomly. The square has equal side lengths of between 20 and 30 pixels.

I'd like to write a Java program to find the exact center of this square. I know there must be a way to do this extremely fast. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: find the (coordinates of) first and the last pixel that is green or non-white - mean value of coordinates is the center of the square

Comment: Assuming you have a raster of all the color values of the image, you do a variation of a binary search until you find one non-white pixel.  Then you do a variation of a flood fill to find the coordinate of the top left non-white pixel and the coordinate of the bottom right non-white pixel.  As @user16320675 said, you find the mean of the two coordinates.  And, no, this will not be fast.

Comment: instead of binary search, you can also search every 20th pixel per direction (since the square is at least 20 pixels width) to find one pixel of the square and then use binary search to find the corners (we know they are at most 30 pixels apart)

Comment: Yes looking every 20th and 30th pixel is the way binary search and flood fill is useless for this will be too slow. Just be carefull JPG is lossy so the color values will have noise in it

Comment: @user16320675 yes but I am afraid that added overhead of binary search will slow things down for such small rectangles

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone who helped. Your comments were useful.

I found that the most efficient way to do this was to just use a quasi-brute force method. I walk the pixel grid with a step of 30 pixels in both x and y direction. The images I'm searching ar around 2k X 2k, so this is pretty quick. Once I find one pixel, I just create a neighborhood around it that's 30 pixes in each direction. This way I can find exactly where the square is.

Two more benefits. I did find that many pixels were almost the correct color due to roundoff error from the producer. I was also able to see that the squares were exactly 30 pixels on each side. If they aren't, I know there's a problem with the process that producces it.

In actual practice, this code is far faster than I would have imagined - no need to try and optimize.